# Can an AWS Lambda function call another

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have 2 Lambda functions - one that produces a quote and one that turns a quote into an order.
I'd like the Order lambda function to call the Quote function to regenerate the quote, rather than just receive it from an untrusted client.

I've looked everywhere I can think of - but can't see how I'd go about chaining or calling the functions...surely this exists!

Comment: I'm reaching here, but why couldn't you depend on the AWS JavaScript SDK in the first Lambda function, create an [AWS.Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html) client and [invoke](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property) the second function?

Comment: It's what I was going to try - but I wasn't entirely sure how to go about it, as there wasn't any examples of doing it from another Lambda function.

Comment: apparently you can also invoke a Lambda function through [HTTP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html).

Comment: and one more idea, you could [chain them through SNS](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1VE917Z8J4UDY/Invoking-AWS-Lambda-functions-via-Amazon-SNS), which is probably the way I'd go as a more scalable strategy

Comment: @devonlazarus it used to be chaining through SNS could provide a good async way of calling Lambda but now you can do this directly I believe. Do you still think it's a better approach going through SNS? Also, I assume SNS implies async, the example marked correct is a synchronous call so probably for these situations SNS should not be considered. Agree?

Comment: @ken agree. if you're looking for 'synchronous' execution of Lambdas, then I would have one Lambda call the other directly.

Comment: Another common alternatives not being mentioned here are Step Functions or SWF.

Comment: Can I call the other Lambda if it resides inside a VPC and the caller lambda is outside that VPC?

Comment: @ManthanJamdagni invocation of a Lambda function is completely independent of that Lambda function's VPC configuration. VPC subnets, routing, security groups etc. are irrelevant (specifically wrt invocation).

Answer (score 494, accepted):

I found a way using the `aws-sdk`.

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var lambda = new aws.Lambda({
  region: 'us-west-2' //change to your region
});

lambda.invoke({
  FunctionName: 'name_of_your_lambda_function',
  Payload: JSON.stringify(event, null, 2) // pass params
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) {
    context.done('error', error);
  }
  if (data.Payload) {
    context.succeed(data.Payload);
  }
});
```

You can find the doc here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html

Comment: Using SNS is probably the better approach, but this is the correct answer.

Comment: i could be wrong, but I think because the invocation is synchronous that the first lambda waits for the second lambda to terminate, thus you will be accruing charges while both lambdas are running.  using SNS, the first lambda should terminate and allow the second lambda to execute independently.

Comment: I was able to get this to work thanks to the `InvocationType: 'Event'` parameter (add it after `FunctionName` and `Payload`). From the docs: _"You can optionally request asynchronous execution by specifying Event as the InvocationType."_ With async execution, the callback function will be reliably called, but without having to wait for the invoked lambda to finish executing.

Comment: Note that the calling lambda function's role needs to include IAM policy `AWSLambdaRole`. Or, you can add the following statement object to your role's existing policy: '{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        ],
        "Resource": ["*"]
    }`

Comment: Have a look at lambda destinations

Comment: Also, be cautious when using this approach for calling the function itself. You might end up in an infinite invocation loop and the only way to stop the invocations, in that case, is be uploading a new version of the code.

Answer (score 162):

You should chain your Lambda functions via SNS. This approach provides good performance, latency and scalability for minimal effort.

Your first Lambda publishes messages to your SNS topic and the second Lambda is subscribed to this topic. As soon as messages arrive in the topic, the second Lambda is executed with the message as its input parameter.

See [Invoking Lambda functions using Amazon SNS notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda.html).

You can also use this approach to [Invoke cross-account Lambda functions via SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-example.html).

Comment: which is the better aproach SNS or Kinesis? I'm really in doubt, thanks.

Comment: Kinesis may be a bit more complicated, but if you're looking at more robust solution, then it may be a good option for you. Also, SNS doesn't store the incoming events, Kinesis does.

Comment: I added them to the post.

Comment: "You should chain your Lambda functions via SNS" -- can you support this with evidence/links to docs? I see how both methods would work, I would be interested in seeing some opinions / definite statements on which one is the preferred one

Comment: It depends on your use case so there is no definitive answer. If you look at the number of upvotes on this, people successfully use it.

Comment: This is a good idea if you need it to be asynchronous. 
But if your first lambda function *needs* the returned value from the second lambda, you have to chain the lambdas and have the first lambda function invoke the second lambda function directly.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using SNS. You can just utilize the asynchronous invocation API for the lambda function-no reason to use SNS unless you want to notify multiple subscribers and not just trigger another lambda function.

Comment: Keep in mind that SNS does not have delivery guarantee so you'd might fire the message but it might not arrive.

Comment: Yes. When there's no subscriber it won't deliver the message, but that's a feature not a problem.

Comment: Using this scenario also adds costs for SNS usage, which isn't the best practice imo

Comment: Of course, but you pay for all the benefits from the first paragraph.

Comment: @adamkinrad what benefits from the first paragraph? There weren't any benefits listed except "look at all the upvotes". If the use case is one lambda triggering another then using SNS would be bad practice due to added complexity and cost wit no apparent benefits.

Comment: @Kuranes You're right that the benefits are not clear. Invoking Lambdas directly from one another means your code is coupled. If you use SNS, you can easily change the design of your system (Launch multiple Lambdas, Queue Events, Launch something else). This is why SNS is what I prefer.

Comment: In order to solve the problem of delivery guarantee you can notify to an SQS queue and use retry patters to ensure the successfully processing the data. 

https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/

Answer (score 108):

Here's a sample code for python,

```
from boto3 import client as boto3_client
from datetime import datetime
import json

lambda_client = boto3_client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    msg = {"key": "new_invocation", "at": datetime.now().isoformat()}
    invoke_response = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName="another_lambda_",
                                           InvocationType='Event',
                                           Payload=json.dumps(msg))
    print(invoke_response)
```

Btw, you would need to add a policy like this to your lambda role as well

```
   {
        "Sid": "Stmt1234567890",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
```

Comment: The documentation seems to suggest the payload must be JSON. Is it possible to send binary data?

Comment: I prefer this method also, but it's got one glitch. You'll need to convert the `datetime.now()` to a string (or handle it somehow). Otherwise, you get the error `datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 11, 14, 40, 53, 23834) is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Is it possible to be more restrictive in the first lambda's role?  Ie, to tie it down to invoking _specific_ functions, rather than any and all?

Comment: @Phil maybe the "Resource" field can be set to allow only a specific set of functions, I am not completely sure though

Comment: Answer to my own comment, through personal experience is yes, you can.  I'll propose an edit.

Comment: The `InvocationType` should be: `RequestResponse`. To get the response from the lambda that you are trying to invoke.

Comment: And then if you have `InvocationType` to `RequestResponse` you should print `print(invoke_response['Payload'].read().decode())` to properly print the response message

Answer (score 53):

Since this question was asked, Amazon has released Step Functions (https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/).

One of the core principles behind AWS Lambda is that you can focus more on business logic and less on the application logic that ties it all together. Step functions allows you to orchestrate complex interactions between functions without having to write the code to do it.

Answer (score 19):

This solution is done using boto3 and Python:

```
import boto3
import json

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda', region_name='eu-west-1')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName = 'function_name', InvocationType = 'RequestResponse', Payload = json.dumps(event))
    
    return True
```

Comment: InvocationType
Choose from the following options.

RequestResponse (default) - Invoke the function synchronously. Keep the connection open until the function returns a response or times out.

Event - Invoke the function asynchronously. Send events that fail multiple times to the function's dead-letter queue (if configured).

DryRun - Validate parameter values and verify that the user or role has permission to invoke the function.

Answer (score 13):

I was looking at cutting out SNS until I saw this in the [Lambda client docs (Java version)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html):

> Client for accessing AWS Lambda. All service calls made using this client are blocking, and will not return until the service call completes.

So SNS has an obvious advantage: it's asynchronous.  Your lambda won't wait for the subsequent lambda to complete.

Comment: InvocationType='Event' makes it async. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property

Comment: @Ankit that should be the selected answer, I was misled to believe using SNS was the only way to do an asynchronous invocation because nobody answered with this information.

Comment: @Ankit do you know of an example using InvocationType='Event' but from Java instead of JavaScript? There is a ton of Java documentation, but not nearly as many examples as JavaScript

Comment: SNS still adds costs for it's usage

Comment: @SebastienH. There is no cost for SNS invoking Lambda. https://aws.amazon.com/sns/pricing/

Answer (score 11):

Amazon has introduced steps functions in AWS lambda in 2016. I think, now it's more convenient to use steps function as it's really easy to use them. You can build a state machine with two lambda functions as:

- to produces a quote
- turns a quote into an order

You can easily do that as below:

*Here you can have first state for produces a quote and another to turns into order*

```
{
  Comment: "Produce a quote and turns into an order",
  StartAt: "ProduceQuote",
  States: {
    ProduceQuote: {
      "Type": Task,
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:ProduceQuote",
      "next": TurnsToOrder
    }
    TurnsToOrder: {
      Type: Task,
      Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:ProduceQuote",
      end: true
    }
  }
}
```

Steps functions makes it really easy to write multiple lambda functions and run in sequence or in parallel.
You can get more information about lambda steps functions here:
[Steps Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html)

Answer (score 10):

There are a lot of answers, but none is stressing that calling another lambda function is not recommended solution for synchronous calls and the one that you should be using is really **Step Functions**

Reasons why it is not recommended solution:

- you are paying for both functions when they are waiting for each other
- your code is responsible for retrials

You can also use it for quite complex logic, such as parallel steps and catch failures. Every execution is also being logged out which makes debugging much simpler.

Answer (score 6):

In java, we can do as follows :

```
AWSLambdaAsync awsLambdaAsync = AWSLambdaAsyncClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-east-1").build();

InvokeRequest invokeRequest = new InvokeRequest();
invokeRequest.withFunctionName("youLambdaFunctionNameToCall").withPayload(payload);

InvokeResult invokeResult = awsLambdaAsync.invoke(invokeRequest);
```

Here, payload is your **stringified** java object which needs to be passed as Json object to another lambda in case you need to pass some information from calling lambda to called lambda.

Comment: how can i pass path parameters that is required by the target lambda?

Answer (score 5):

I was working with the answer provided by **blueskin** but I could not read the Payload response because the **InvocationType='Event'** is **async**, so I changed as InvocationType='RequestResponse' and now all works good.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to make use of the Async.js Waterfall feature - see the bottom part of the big code chunk in Step 3 of this document for an example:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/better-together-amazon-ecs-and-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 3):

Others pointed out to use SQS and Step Functions. But both these solutions add additional cost. Step Function state transitions are supposedly very expensive.

AWS lambda offers some retry logic. Where it tries something for 3 times. I am not sure if that is still valid when you trigger it use the API.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the python example of calling another lambda function and gets its response. There is two invocation type **'RequestResponse'** and **'Event'**. Use 'RequestResponse' if you want to get the response of lambda function and use 'Event' to invoke lambda function asynchronously. So both ways asynchronous and synchronous are available.

```
    lambda_response = lambda_client.invoke(
                FunctionName = lambda_name,
                InvocationType = 'RequestResponse',
                Payload = json.dumps(input)
                )
    resp_str = lambda_response['Payload'].read()
    response = json.loads(resp_str)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke lambda function directly (at least via Java) by using `AWSLambdaClient` as described in the AWS' blog [post](https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx2J2LPKTTVU93H/Invoking-AWS-Lambda-Functions-from-Java).

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem but the Lambda function that I implement will insert an entry in DynamoDB, so my solution uses DynamoDB Triggers.

I make the DB invoke a Lambda function for every insert/update in the table, so this separates the implementation of two Lambda functions.

Documentation is here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html

Here is a guided walkthrough:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-triggers-streams-lambda-cross-region-replication-app/

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a roundabout solution but I just call the **API endpoint** for my lambda functions when I need to chain them. This allows you to decide while coding if you want them to be asynchronous or not.

In case you don't want to setup a POST request you can just setup a simple GET request with a couple, or none at all, query string parameters for easy event passing.

*-- Edit --*

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/making-http-requests/

and: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https-example.html

Comment: this seems a lot less roundabout than SNS, but then i don't have much experience using SNS

Comment: Can you share the code needed to call an API endpoint from within a lambda?

Comment: @Glenn it's just an ajax request. Tag on your parameters that you need to as query parameters. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/making-http-requests/ and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https-example.html

Comment: Another problem is that going through API Gateway is relatively expensive compared to calling another Lambda function. 

A 128MB function running for 100ms (the minimum) costs $0.21 per 1 million calls, whereas API Gateway costs $3.50 per 1 million. Obviously, if you're running for more time or you use more ram, you'd have to multiply the 21 cents, but still, $3.50 per million is really expensive. (These prices were effective as of August 2017)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it in javascript/typescript without having to install complete aws-sdk package.

```
import { InvokeCommand, LambdaClient, LogType } from "@aws-sdk/client-lambda";

const client = new LambdaClient({
    region: "US-EAST-1"
});

const payload = JSON.stringify({
  data: "your input"
})

const command = new InvokeCommand({
  FunctionName: "your function name",
  Payload: payload,
  LogType: LogType.Tail,
});

const { Payload } = await client.send(command);
const response: any = Payload;
const result = Buffer.from(response).toString();

return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger Lambda functions directly from other Lambda functions directly in an asynchronous manner.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#invocation-async-destinations

Answer (score 0):

Calling another function from one function is considered as antipattern in server less. Its well explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/functions-calling-functions.html).

Better implementaion is either use queue to publish the message and consume in another lambda or use step function as described by [Black](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65369409/revisions)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use a lambda function dependent on another lambda function. you can use the [State Machine] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-state-machine-structure.html this will help you run the lambda function in sequence or based on the result of another lambda function. It also allows you to integrate other AWS Services also

Answer (score 0):

You might consider use the Service **AWS Step Function**, this allow to you orchestrate many lambdas sharing a common space of variables and data.

https://aws.amazon.com/pt/step-functions/

here there an example of a state machine:

[image]