# Best way to parallelize AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a large file being uploaded on S3, and for each line in the file I need to make a long running rest API call.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to break up the work.  My current flow idea is

Lambda (break up file by line) -> SNS (notification per line) ->  Lambda (separate per line/notification)

This seems like it is a common use case, but I can't find many references to it, am I missing something?  Is there a better option to break up my work and get it done in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: Why not skip the middle step and just call a second lambda function from the first one?  Kind of like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714788/can-an-aws-lambda-function-call-another

Comment: How long is your `long running rest API call`?

Answer (score 2):

The *Best* way is going to be subjective. The method you are using currently, `Lambda->SNS->Lambda`, is one possible method. As JohnAllen pointed out, you could simply do `Lambda->Lambda`.

Your scenario reminds me of [this project](https://github.com/ryansb/hugo-lambda), which has a single Lambda function adding items to a Kinesis stream, which then triggers many parallel Lambda functions.

I think `Lambda->Kinesis->Lambda` might be a better fit for your use case than `Lambda->SNS->Lambda` if you are generating a very large number of Lambda tasks. I would be worried that the SNS implementation would run up against the maximum number of concurrent Lambda functions, while the Kinesis implementation would queue them up and handle that gracefully.