# HTTP 200 OK response not working

Tags: php, slack, slack-api

I am using slack, built a BOT that and subscribed an event `message.group`
I want to build my projects via my BOT, once I post my predefined deploy command it will start execution the script I built, but it will try again and again by self after post a single command.

slack documentation says:

> Your app should respond to the event request with an HTTP 2xx within three seconds. If it does not, we'll consider the event delivery attempt failed. After a failure, we'll retry three times, backing off exponentially.
>   We recommend responding to events with a HTTP 200 OK as soon as you can. You may want to avoid processing and reacting to events within the same process handling event reception.

I have set below code at the beginning of my script like this way-

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
echo "HTTP 200 OK";
```

it dose not work

Comment: Are you working on localhost? or shared IP?

Comment: @ShaunakShukla I have uploaded my script in a server

Comment: You should send response with 2xx code to slack service, where is that part of code?

Comment: @VaheGalstyan actually I do not understand how should I send response with 2xx
I just printed this code at top of my script
`header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
echo "HTTP 200 OK";`

Answer (score 0):

Add Header, and return something

```
header('HTTP/1.1 200 Success', true, 200);
return 'Success';
```

Comment: still responding more than one.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Responding with HTTP OK to the calling server in the midst of a running PHP script is not trivial. The web server will in most cases prevent any OK sending before the script is terminated. There are two general approaches that will work:

1. Manage output puffer and force webserver to send OK back (depends on webserver configuration)
2. Start 2nd script asynchronously to process request further and terminate 1st script within 3 secs. (which will automatically send an HTTP OK back)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195924/slack-php-api-avoid-timeout-error) for an explanation on how to implement those approaches for Slack in PHP.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42272824/4379151) for a solution that worked for me.

Comment: if I want to TURNING RETRIES OFF how can I set `X-Slack-No-Retry: 1` as header response?