# Slack command timeout error firing only on mobile (before 3000 ms)

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-dialog

I am doing exactly as said in the docs: sending instant 200 responses after receiving commands.
Exactly as @rcoup is saying in [How to avoid slack command timeout error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896954/how-to-avoid-slack-command-timeout-error).

And it works perfectly on slack desktop. No error messages at all.
However, when I invoke the commands on slack for iOS, these 503 timeout messages keep showing up. Weirdly, sometimes they show up AFTER the response is already there. :/

Is there any different time limit or nay different approach for mobile? Couldn't find anything within their docs.

Comment: No, there is no different time out limit. It looks more like your HTTP 200 response is not working properly, or your backend maybe has latency issues (e.g. a cloud function starting up on each request may take more than 3 secs). Please add the relevant part of your code and let us know what tech stack you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you for your feedback Erik.
We figure that we were giving the right 200 feedback on the first user message, but after we start to show interactive components on the same dialog, we stopped giving the instant 200 answers. 
It is interesting because we are actually giving answers back before 3000ms after the user has clicked on an interactive component. But, on mobile, it looks like that the answers need to be a direct answer to the component interaction request and not just any answer back like we were doing (fetching data and returning, even if it is before 3000ms).

So, there is definitely some difference in behaviors between desktop and mobile..
The way we were doing, Desktop never gave us timeouts, Mobile always gives us timeouts.