Slack slash command failed with the error "operation_timeout" sending http request to Azure function written in Powershell
I have an Azure function that does a bunch of API calls and takes longer than 3 seconds which is why Slack gives me that message. I've read that I need to send back a response immediately, but I don't know exactly how to do it. I'm using Powershell. At the end of the code, there is this:
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})

And that sends off the output to Slack. I tried putting one of those at the very top of the function code with just $body='hello', but I still get the message and I never get 'hello' in Slack. If I put 'exit' immediately after that code, I get the message in Slack. What can I do to just tell Slack to relax while the function runs?
Trying to get Slack to let my function run, but unsure of the syntax to tell it what I need to. Also in Azure everything looks ok and successful in application insights for the function.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896954/how-to-avoid-slack-command-timeout-error for how to handle the slack side. As for how to handle the Azure side, you can enqueue the work for async handling, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/async-request-reply and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-powershell

I read those, but I still don't know how to make it work in the context of a Powershell Azure Function. It said to send a 200 straight-away and I did, but it just didn't send.
There's also an issue where all the body data is one long string with %2s and %3S, and I can't retrieve the response_url. Part of the problem is no one(in my searches) does this in Powershell and I can't find any references to working code.
