# Serverless express app terminates before logic within route has completed

Tags: express, serverless-framework

I have a simple Express app, hosted on AWS, using the Serverless framework.

I'm using `serverless-http` to wrap the express app for deployment to an AWS lambda function, and `express-async-await` to allow the use of async functions for routes.

For one of my routes I want to return a page to the user then continue performing various async tasks. Here is an abbreviated version of my code:

```
const serverless = require("serverless-http");
const express = require("express");
const mustacheExpress = require("mustache-express");
const aa = require("express-async-await");

// configure our express app
const app = aa(express());
app.use(express.static("static"));
app.engine("html", mustacheExpress());
app.set("view engine", "html");
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
app.get("/", async (request, response) => {

  response.render("generating", {  });

  // various async tasks
  await s3.putObject({ });
  await s3.putObject({ });

});

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

However, from inspecting the logs I can see that the tasks that follow the `response.render` stop mid-way. The lambda returns without an error, no timeouts, but the tasks are stopped.

Moving `response.render` to the end of the route means that the async tasks are executed, however, the user sees a spinner rather than a rendered HTML holding pages.

From reading around, I've found numerous references that indicate Express is more than happy to continue execution after a response has been returned.

Any ideas what is going wrong in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this use case is not presently possible with Lambda and API Gateway, as the invocation to Lambda from API Gateway is of type `RequestResponse`, and not of type `Async`. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219599/respond-then-continue-working-with-aws-lambda-api-gateway)

Once your code (which in this case I believe is `serverless-express`) calls `context.done()`, the response is sent from Lambda to API Gateway and the execution context of the Lambda function is finished (either frozen, to be re-used in the next invocation, or recycled into Lambda's underlying infrastructure).

There are several options to invoke a new function to continue processing, so your API can return to the user:

- Publish a message to an SNS topic and/or an SQS queue and build a second lambda to process the messages
- Use Step Functions
- Use the AWS-SDK to directly invoke a second function

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the AWS lambda function is terminating the execution after the response is written.

¿Are you using promises with S3? Shouldn't the code to upload be:

```js
await s3.putObject({ }).promise();
```

Try that. However I would also suggest moving the `response.render` to the end of the route and handling things from the front-end. For example:

```js
// show spinner

// make AJAX request and handle the result asynchronously, for example, assuming you are using axios:
axios.get(url).then(data => {
  // show result to the user
})

// hide spinner and show other HTML while the request finishes
```