# How can I call another Lambda function from current Lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have 2 Lambda function. First fetch data from database and put it in DynamoDB. And Second fetch data from the DynamoDB. I want to execute both lambda function sequentially (i.e.first then second). How could **I invoke 2nd Lambda function inside 1st Lambda function?** **How to pass data to that Lambda function**? And **how to get response from the 2nd Lambda function?** Does anyone know possible way? Please help.... Thank u....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an AWS Lambda function call another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714788/can-an-aws-lambda-function-call-another)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For nodejs you can use lambda.invoke function to execute another lambda

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
var lambda = new aws.Lambda({
  region: "us-west-1",
});

var params = {
  FunctionName: "MyFunction",
  InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
  LogType: "Tail",
  Payload: "<Stringified oject to pass parameters as event>",
};


lambda.invoke(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
  // an error occurred
  else console.log(data); // successful response
});
```

for info visit this link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property

Comment: If in some case I dont want to pass any data to 2nd function but want to receive data from it, is it possible?

Comment: Is there any changes required in 2nd function?

Comment: No changes required in the second function.

Comment: in Payload just pass an empty string and you will get data returned by second function in data object

Comment: That worked.... Thank u.... Now 1 last question I am getting desired output in log every time but null in response.. callback(null,cde);  // not working &
 console.log(cde);   //working.....

Comment: Share jsfiddle link if possible