# Does AWS Step function make the latency higher than direct Lambda call chaining?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am trying to chain two lambda functions together, and my application is somewhat latency sensitive (the lower the better).

I think AWS Step function certainly can help me achieving this function chain, but I am not sure what the latency implication this approach means here (I guess step function may introduce non trivial latency between the orchestrated steps).

Another way to achieve this is directly call another lambda as described in this [Can an AWS Lambda function call another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714788/can-an-aws-lambda-function-call-another) (See the answers from @blueskin, @Trilok Nagvenkar)

Can we say approach 2 is bound to be much more fast from system design perspective than approach 1? Or the Step Function way does not cause extra latency at all?