# AWS creds error when making calls from local react app "Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I'm getting the following error when running my react app locally which make an api request to AWS via the AWS-SDK:

```
CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
```

I've tried:

- I've tried [exporting my aws credentials directly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-environment.html)
- I already have my aws credentials set up in ~/.aws/credentials and I use the CLI everyday with no issue
- I've tried copying the ~/.aws directory to my project root
- I've tried using dotenv and a config file  [as suggested in these replies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61028751/missing-credentials-in-config-if-using-aws-config-file-set-aws-sdk-load-config)

This is how I'm making the request:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const ssm = new AWS.SSM({ region: 'eu-west-1' });

export const useFetchParams = (initialValue) => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState(initialValue);

    useEffect(() => {
        const params = {
            Path: '/',
            MaxResults: '2',
            Recursive: true,
            WithDecryption: true
        };

        ssm.getParametersByPath(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
            else setResult(data);
        });
    }, []);

    return result;
};

export default useFetchParams;
```

Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error states that credentials are missing so it is an authentication issue, you can try setting the `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey` or the `credentials` fields directly on the SSM constructor.

So simply maintain your code as is, just make the following change:

```
// From
const ssm = new AWS.SSM({ region: 'eu-west-1' });

// To
const ssm = new AWS.SSM({
    region: 'eu-west-1',
    accessKeyId: 'your-access-key',
    secretAccessKey: 'your-secret-key'
});

// Or To
const ssm = new AWS.SSM({
    region: 'eu-west-1',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: 'your-access-key',
        secretAccessKey: 'your-secret-key'
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea! You should never hardcode your credentials like this. This should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for your informative comment @jbnunn but where exactly does it say hardcode your credentials...
OP can easily use env variables, but thats not the point of his question

Comment: Are you not suggesting OP hardcodes their credentials on lines 7 and 8 with `accessKeyId: 'your-access-key'`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to hardcode credentials like this. I'd use a library like [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv), then creating an `.env.local` file with your credentials, like so:

```
REACT_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=YOUR-KEY
REACT_APP_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=YOUR-ACCESS-ID
```

In your script, configure the AWS SDK with:

```
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: 'us-east-1', 
});
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue here. I am tring to call a lambda function from my react app. The lambda function is meant to start an AWS job. When I call the lambda function (on click of a button from react app), it says "Error invoking Lambda: Error: Credential is missing". So if I've to follow the above, should I expose the real accessKeyId and secretAccessKey in .env file? (In react its still called as .env file?) Thanks

Comment: You can use Amazon Cognito for this. Create a User Pool with a role that allows the invocation of your Lambda function.