# Can I call an AWS lambda from a script?

Tags: aws-lambda

I already have the lambda python function written and the perl script written.  I just can't figure out how to call the python function from perl.  I would put the perl script in a custom lambda runtime but my perl script runs for a lot longer that 15 minutes.  If someone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/calling-an-aws-lambda-function-from-another-lambda-function/

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [invoke a lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) with a web request.

Also, there's [Can an AWS Lambda function call another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714788/can-an-aws-lambda-function-call-another), among with many other resources out there (and on this site even), that have examples. In Perl, the [PAWS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Paws) module handle parts of the AWS interface.

Comment: PAWS will be the way that I go as soon as I figure out how to add it to my AWS EC2 Instance