# AWS TS CDK how to execute Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have 2 AWS Lambda functions defined using AWS CDK. The stack has them defined pretty straight forward.

How do I call Lambda function 2 from Lambda function 1? Is using state machines (AWS Step Functions) really the only way? I don't mind them but would really like to know how to call a Lambda function in code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can an AWS Lambda function call another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714788/can-an-aws-lambda-function-call-another)

Comment: You can simply call the `invoke()` API.

Comment: There are so many ways to call a Lambda from another Lambda. You have describe more details as to why you want to do this so we can point you to the right direction. Also, this is not CDK-related.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be triggering Lambda 2 event driven. You can create an SNS topic and register it as destination for Lambda 1 and as trigger for Lambda 2.

Comment: responses are required